# Counting non-zero elements in a sparse matrix using breeze

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I'm new to breeze. I can't seem to be able to count the number of non-zero element per row in a `CSCMatrix`.

Let's take the following example :

```scala
val matrix = CSCMatrix.tabulate(3, 2)((x,y) => x*y)
```

This is a sparse matrix of dimension 3x2:

```
|0|0|
|0|1|
|0|2|
```

What I want is to compute the number of non-zero elements per row, so the output should be a vector of the form:

```
|0|
|1|
|1|
```

It would be easy to do it with numpy, but I can't seem to be able to do it with breeze.

Comment: There's no simple way to do this in Breeze. If you open an issue I'll look into it. For columns, there's a relatively compact way to do it by looping over colPtrs, though it's still not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone still needs this, you may do it with a Matrix vector multiplication in the following way:

```
matrix * DenseVector.ones[Int](matrix.cols)
```